# how to select to open specific text file

Tags: python, sorting

```
menu = {}
menu['1']="1" 
menu['2']="2"
menu['3']="3"
while True: 
  options=menu.keys()
  options.sort()
  for entry in options: 
      print (entry, menu[entry])

    selection = input('Please Select:')

    if selection =='1':
        file = open("1.txt")      
    elif selection == '2':
        file = open("2.txt")     
    elif selection == '3':
        file = open("3.txt")
```

hi i would like to be able to select a specific text file to open. So say if '1' is inputted that text file opens and so on.

Comment: You should add some tags related to the technology you are working with.

Comment: What is wrong with your solution?

Answer (score 0):

This will place the user's selection into the file string to open.

```
menu = {}
menu['1']="1" 
menu['2']="2"
menu['3']="3"
while True: 
  options=menu.keys()
  options.sort()
  for entry in options: 
      print (entry, menu[entry])

    selection = input('Please Select:')
    file = open("{}.txt".format(selection))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to prepend the input to the string of the filename:

```
selection = input('Please Select:')
file = open(selection + ".txt")
```

This may not be safe though as the user may be able to specify their own file name.

You may want to use your hashmap instead so that it the text prepended to the .txt string will never be anything other than what you have in the list:

```
selection = input('Please Select:')
file = open(menu[selection] + ".txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the dict values fit into it but you can use str.format to open the file if they are numbered:

```
menu = {'1': "1", '2': "2", '3': "3"}
options = sorted(options.items())
while True:
    for entry, v in options:
        print (entry, v)   
        selection = input('Please Select:')
        if selection in menu:
            break
        print("Invalid choice")

with open("{}.txt".format(selection)) as f:
        ...
```

If you are actually using the dict values just check if the selection is valid i.e in the dict keys and then open using the values :

```
menu = {'1': "1.txt", '2': "2.txt", '3': "3.txt"}
options = sorted(options.items())
while True:
    for entry, v in options:
        print (entry, v)
        selection = input('Please Select:')
        if selection in menu:
            break
        print("Invalid choice")
with open(menu[selection]) as f:
                ...
```

If you are using python3 which you must seem to be, you cannot call sort on dict.keys as .keys() returns a dictview object not a list so  options = `sorted(options.items())` will actually give you a sorted list of the items which you can unpack in the for loop.